# Absorption respose of cones in eye

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, medical-physics

I am trying to find information about the absorption response of the cones in the eye to different wavelengths of light. I have noticed two types of graphs and answers: one which shows the S-absorption peaking at about 420 nm, and another which shows it peaking at about 440 nm. What is the difference between these two?

For example, [this link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13414-020-02216-7/tables/1) (https://doi.org/10.3758/s13414-020-02216-7) shows a table where the mean of the S-cone peak is 442.3 nm. Of the 16 studies used to arrive at this mean, not a single one is below 438 nm. Wikipedia has the following graph in it's article [Cone Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell):

[image]

Showing a peak near 440 nm.

On the other hand, the Wikipedia article itself says, *"The third type [S] responds the most to blue short-wavelength light, peaking at 420 nm,"* which corroborates other sources like [this one](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-540-69000-9_77) (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-69000-9_77) which says, "All humans with normal color vision have the same S-cone pigment, with peak absorption around 417 nanometers (nm)," and shows the following graph:
[image]

Another source [here](https://www.unm.edu/%7Etoolson/human_cone_response.htm#:%7E:text=In%20humans%2C%20the%20three%20classes,spectrum%20is%20not%20to%20scale%3B) says, "*In humans, the three classes of cone show maximal absorption efficiency at wavelengths (lmax) of 420 nm (blue cones), 530 nm (green cones) and 560 nm (red cones), as illustrated by the following graph (I’ve included the absorption spectrum for rods as well, but the graph of the rod absorption spectrum is not to scale; it’s included solely for comparative purposes.*"

[image]

Comment: The one with max at 440 is just not accurate, but just a sketch.

Comment: @trula Check out the first Springer link, though